# How to tell what is changing a windows environment variable

Tags: windows

I have a (win8) system where, each time it is rebooted, something is modifying the HOME environment variable.

This is causing problems, and I want to track down what is modifying it.

Is there any way to tell what is modifying that environment variable?

Comment: Not an easy task. If you are in an AD environment, group policy is probably doing it. If not, look at everything that runs at startup. You could also use procmon to monitor registry changes during startup.

Answer (score 11):

[Monitoring when registry keys are modified](https://web.archive.org/web/20160219222659/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cobold/archive/2011/11/29/monitoring-when-registry-keys-are-modified.aspx):

What we need to do is:

1. ```
     Run the following command from Command Prompt:

    auditpol /set /subcategory:"Registry" /success:enable
   ```

Note: if the OS has a different language pack, the name `Registry` might differ. For instance, on a German Windows, the name is `Registrierung`. To see what the name of the subcategory is you can run:

```
auditpol /list /subcategory:*
```

2. ```
     Open Registry Editor and navigate to the key which we want to audit
   ```

- User Variables: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment`
- System Variables (`PATH` is a system variable): `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment\`

3. ```
     Right-click on the key and choose `Permissions…`
   ```

[image]

4. ```
     Click `Advanced` and switch to the `Auditing` tab
   ```

[image]

5. ```
     Add a user or group and select Access: Set Value
   ```
6. ```
     Apply settings
   ```

Now the registry changes are visible in the Event Viewer under `Windows Logs\Security`:

[image]

Comment: I added a German Language pack to a Server 2016 VM and the category and subcategory list is now completely in English and not dependent on the language pack installed on the system.