# Tracking down why Group Policy Client is changing an environment variable

Tags: windows-7, r

Something is mysteriously changing one of my environment variables on my Win 7 system.  I've followed the guidance in [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/896263/how-to-tell-what-is-changing-a-windows-environment-variable), and tracked down the culprit... to svchost.exe.  Process Explorer seems to indicate that that thread of svchost.exe is running the Group Policy Client (gpsvc).  Any thoughts about how to track down why gpsvc is changing this environment variable, and how to stop it from doing so?

Thanks in advance...

```
A registry value was modified.

Subject:
    Security ID:        SYSTEM
    Account Name:       machine$
    Account Domain:     mydomain
    Logon ID:       0xfff

Object:
    Object Name:        \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-21-1657032316-61167162-621696214-25666\Environment
    Object Value Name:  R_LIBS
    Handle ID:      0x16c
    Operation Type:     Existing registry value modified

Process Information:
    Process ID:     0x474
    Process Name:       C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe

Change Information:
    Old Value Type:     REG_SZ
    Old Value:      D:\Program Files\R_libs
    New Value Type:     REG_SZ
    New Value:      z:\R
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your environment variable is set by a group policy setting, try to run in a priviledged command prompt :

```
gpupdate /r /z > somefile.txt && notepad somefile.txt
```

Then search inside the text file for your environment variable.

I am not sure if the result are the same but you may also try :

```
gpupdate /h report.html && start report.html
```

Then search inside in your browser for the environment variable.

Comment: Thanks @rebrec.  I can't see anything referencing environment variables, or any of the registry references touching the environment variables, there.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: can you change back your environment variable, then run `gpupdate /force` and see if the variable is modified again ?

Comment: yep, that changed it...

Comment: umm in fact, it seems that rsop.msc is deprecated... can you try in a priviledged command prompt `gpresult /r /z > somefile.txt` and then open that file and search for the occurence of your environment variable ? You can also try `gpresult /h somefile.html && notepad somefile.html` and then search for the variable again.

Comment: Thanks rebrec.  gpresult /r /z came up with nothing, but gpresult /h shows that R_LIBS is set in the group policy preferences (user configuration -> references -> environment variables):  https://i.imgur.com/FpFEobP.png  .  I've been poking around, but can't find a way to access those preferences.  Any thoughts?  If it's something administered by the IT staff at a domain level, I can ping them about it...  Thanks again...

Comment: Good news that you have found where it was located, indeed GP preferences are the place to configure environment variables. GPO are definately defined by your IT Staff. You won't be able to change them yourself if you don't have an "admin" level access. To access ths GPO Preference settings for the GPO involved in your environment variable modification, after identifying its name, you can try to run (start / run) `GPME.MSC` (if you have it installed) then choose the expected GPO and look at the GP preference. (you will need domain admin rights to be able to edit it

Comment: Thanks rebrec.  I have admin access on my machine, but not on the domain.  Will contact IT... thank you!