# How to audit the event of setting PSExecutionPolicyPreference?

Tags: windows, powershell, environment-variables

The main problem is that we execute PowerShell scripts and one of our machines changes the Execution Policy during execution for reasons unknown. Goal is to figure out when and why this change happens.

Context: We have a CI pipeline that prepares VMs and then runs a software test suite. One of the preprocessing steps which is executed in the test suite itself sets the PowerShell Execution Policy with

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

This works locally but when the CI is triggered we get an error on one of the machines:

```
Windows PowerShell updated your execution policy successfully, but the setting is overridden by a policy defined at a more specific scope.
Due to the override, your shell will retain its current effective execution policy of RemoteSigned.
```

The reason is that the policy `RemoteSigned` is defined on the Process level for some reason (confirmed by outputting `Get-ExecutionPolicy -List`  and `$env:PSExecutionPolicyPreference` directly before executing the `Set-ExecutionPolicy` step). This policy is still compatible with local PowerShell execution so it does not impact the test suite, however, we want the tests to run uniformly regardless of the machine. Hence I want to figure out what sets the `PSExecutionPolicyPreference` and when.

The test suite itself does not set the policy because then it would happen on other machines as well. And I cannot find anything in the CI pipeline that sets the policy.

There is a post explaining how to [audit changes to the Environment variables](https://superuser.com/questions/896263/how-to-tell-what-is-changing-a-windows-environment-variable) but it applies to variables stored in the Registry where PSExecutionPolicyPreference is not stored (see [Microsoft documentation on Execution Policies](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7.1#execution-policy-scope)).

So, is there a way to determine time and process which set the PSExecutionPolicyReference?

Comment: domain machine? maybe a group policy? [see here - example-2--set-an-execution-policy-that-conflicts-with-a-group-policy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy?view=powershell-7.1#example-2--set-an-execution-policy-that-conflicts-with-a-group-policy), and I did not understand your audit/registry mention in your post. maybe you could use [sysinternals - accesschk](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/accesschk) to see the change

Comment: Enable PowerShell auditing locally and/or enterprise-wide. There are many docs showing how to do this.

Comment: Powershell auditing is the keyword that I was looking for. I'll try it out and reply with a solution in case I found any. Thanks!